# How to add grid in ggsurvplot without changing theme in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to add a solid, lightgrey grid to my `ggsurvplot` without changing ggtheme - quite equivalent to `grids(linetype="solid")` in ggplot().

My data

```
p <- structure(list(Studie = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Age = c(35, 38, 67, 18, 62, 61, 31, 34, 26, 44, 33, 54, 35, 49, 62, 56, 41, 58, 65, 29,63, 63, 51, 56, 44, 45, 47, 67, 56, 54, 41, 78, 53.8, 58.3), WHO = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Death = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Follow.up.death = c(18,2, 14, 17, 31, 4, 20, 15, 12, 19, 10, 17, 27, 22, 3, 43, 24, 14, 13, 5, 12, 137, 22, 87, 48, 24, 72, 32, 14, 83, 57, 16, 70, 1.9)), .Names = c("Studie", "Age", "WHO", "Death", "Follow.up.death"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L))
```

I have used the following script

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(p$Follow.up.death, p$Death) ~ 1 + factor(p$WHO), conf.type="log", data=p)
j <- ggsurvplot(
  fit,                     
  data = p, 
  #fun="cumhaz",
  risk.table = "abs_pct", #risk.table.col="strata",
  pval = TRUE,      
  pval.coord = c(0, 0.25),
  conf.int = F,         
  legend.labs=c("WHO-I", "WHO-II", "WHO-III"),
  cumevents.title = "Cumulative number of deaths",
  size=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),                    
  xlim = c(0,35),
  alpha=c(0.8),
  break.x.by = 5,    
  xlab="Time in months",
  ylab="Probability of overall survival",
  ggtheme = theme_classic2(),             
  risk.table.y.text.col = T,
  risk.table.y.text = TRUE, 
  surv.median.line = "v",
  ylim=c(0,1),
  cumevents=TRUE,
  palette="jco",
  surv.scale="percent")

j
```

Thanks, C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modified the code. I added a new theme in ggtheme.

```
theme <- theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
           panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey90"),
           panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey90"),
           panel.border = element_blank(),
           panel.background = element_blank()) 

j <- ggsurvplot(
  fit,                     
  data = p, 
  #fun="cumhaz",
  risk.table = "abs_pct", #risk.table.col="strata",
  pval = TRUE,      
  pval.coord = c(0, 0.25),
  conf.int = F,         
  legend.labs=c("WHO-I", "WHO-II", "WHO-III"),
  cumevents.title = "Cumulative number of deaths",
  size=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),                    
  xlim = c(0,35),
  alpha=c(0.8),
  break.x.by = 5,    
  xlab="Time in months",
  ylab="Probability of overall survival",
  ggtheme = theme,             
  risk.table.y.text.col = T,
  risk.table.y.text = TRUE, 
  surv.median.line = "v",
  ylim=c(0,1),
  cumevents=TRUE,
  palette="jco",
  tables.theme = theme,
  surv.scale="percent")

j
```

[image]

Comment: No - the grid is correct - but I only want the solid black lines at the exact y-axis and x-axis, not as square around the entire plot. Can you du that? And I want the grid at tables too.

Comment: It is! Can you add it to the tables too? Thank you very much!

Comment: The graph has been modified. I juste replace  tables.theme = theme_classic() by
tables.theme = theme. You're welcome !

Comment: Thank you - much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a "correct" way to do this since I'm not familiar with the survminer package, but you could do this the hacky way:

```
j$plot$theme$panel.grid.major <- element_line(colour="grey90")
```

Edit to add to the tables:

```
j$table$theme$panel.grid.major <- element_line(colour="grey90")
j$cumevents$theme$panel.grid.major <- element_line(colour="grey90")
```

Comment: Partially! Can it be added to the tables too? And can you break grid into different intervals than the break.x.by?

Comment: I edited the answer to add the grid to the tables as well. But I'm not sure what you mean about breaking the grid into different intervals, how many intervals did you want?

Comment: Thank you - very much for your effort, Alex did just solve it.

Comment: Actually better than other options.